# Does wildcard characters behave differently?

Tags: regex, unix, grep, wildcard, glob

I want to understand if behavior of wildcard characters is same or not, for example:

1) On unix prompt, if i type `ls *.xml`, then it lists all files ending with `.xml`, for example: `1.xml, first.xml` etc.

--> So as it appears, * matches any character.

2) Now, i was trying to find some text using `grep` in a file, and i executed following command:

`grep -i "*.xml" first.txt`

To my utter surprise there was no results returned, even though `first.txt` had contents like: `first.xml`, `second.xml`.

If i do `grep -i "xml" first.xml`, then I get the results.

This behavior is causing confusion, how does `*` matches any text in case (1) and in case (2) it is failing?

Does this behave different in different situations, and if so, where to find this info.

Comment: where to find this info ---- `CuriousMind ~ $ man grep`

Comment: Yes :)  I am not sure if man pages would tell Globbing.. thanks for your detailed response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shell uses globbing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)

Grep uses regular expressions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

They are two different languages, and for grep, `*` is not a wild card. It means *the previous character, repeated zero or more times*

You want

```
grep '.*\.xml'
```

which means *any character* (`.`) repeated zero or more times (`*`) followed by a literal '.' (`\.`) xml

(For practical purposes you would just use f`grep .xml` or `grep '\.xml$'` of course)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. So when used in shell what name do we call "*", won't it be referred to wildcard character? I am not sure if the text books do refer to this fact.

Comment: In the shell, it is a wildcard character. In regular expressions (including in grep), it's a Kleene star.

Comment: In a regular expression (in the programming world), it's also known as a "quantifier" along with `+` and `?` and `{m,n}`